# Build project imported from Eclipse git as Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, git, configuration, import

So I used Eclipse git to import an android application's source code and resources into my workspace. Problem is, I imported it as a general project and I'd like to know how to build the project as an android application.

***My Import Options***:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw someone that had this problem. The solution I found was just importing it as a normal android project and the Git Eclipse plugin will notice the .git files in each folder. This will allow you to use the project like a git project AND an android project.

Essentially, don't do anything different from a normal android project and the Git PLugin should work. However, this was the solution for my one situation, it may not apply to all of them.

Comment: I don't see the option to import as an android application.

Comment: Try create a new Android Project, and then choose to create it from an existing source. Browse to your project folder and you'll be done.

Comment: No problem. I'm happy to be able to help.

Comment: And if the git plugin doesn't detect it, you can use Team->Share to correct that.

Answer (score 5):

Edit the `.project` file located in the project's root directory with a text editor and add the android / java natures, then refresh the project in Eclipse.

```
<natures>
    <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, don't understand why Eclipse can't let you do this automatically why I have to edit the .project file by hand.